# How to remove website shortcut icon from all applications

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

I created a website shortcut on the desktop. After I deleted it, the icon under *All installed applications* still exists.

How do I remove it? The icon doesn't exist in `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: See what you have in `~/.local/share/applications`. Maybe there's something there you can get delete.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a Google application shortcut:

1. Go to Chrome browser.
2. Click on the *Apps* icon on the  bookmarks bar.
3. Find the application shortcut there.
4. Right click and click the *Remove* option in menu.

Et voilà, gone!

All web shortcuts are there.

[image: To remove Google application shortcut right-click menu]

Now you can go crazy making little web applets and remove them:

[image: Image of favorites in Ubuntu dock]

Comment: Please don't make people have to click on image links to expand them, it's easier and quicker just to display them in line with the text.